# Indexar correctamente para optimizar una consulta

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

tengo un problema con un tipo de consulta para MongoDB. En una colección de datos tengo indexados casi todos los campos con { a : 1 } , { b : 1 } ... y consultas como la siguiente tienen un rendimiento muy bueno:

```
db.installations.find({deviceToken:"mydevicetoken"})
```

La siguiente consulta con los campos indexados, tarda mucho más por lo que deduzco que no he utilizado de manera correcta la indexación:

```
db.installations.find({ created_at: { $lte : ISODate("2016-12-24T06:44:59.999Z"),
                    $gte : ISODate("2016-12-23T21:45:00Z") } } ).sort( { created_at: 1 })
```

Esta última consulta me arroja mucho tiempo en el mongotop hasta el punto que colapsa la base de datos por el tiempo excesivo de consulta. Alguien sabría decirme como solucionarlo. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Cómo está tu índice actualmente? Ya que si tienes un indice compuesto o múltiple, ese puede ser el factor del exceso de tiempo en la consulta.
Puedes revisarlo con:

```
db.installations.getIndexes()
```

Puedes borrarlo con:

```
db.installations.dropIndex('created_at')
```

Puedes crear un índice simple, con eso debería de bastar para que tu consulta no colapse la base de datos:

```
db.installations.createIndex({created_at: 1})
```

Yo haría la consulta así:

```
db.installations.find({created_at: {$gte: new Date('2016-12-23'), $lt: new Date('2016-12-24')}}).sort({created_at: 1}).pretty()
```

Te dejo la documentación de índices de [mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/)